# Как выполнить функцию по нажатию кнопки в форме? Flask

Tags: html, python, flask

Разрабатываю небольшое API. Мне требуется после нажатия кнопки считать данные из `input'a`, произвести с ними некоторые действия и выввести на экран, если это возможно (Что-то вроде месседжбокса).

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block body %}
    <body>
        <input class="position_center borders" type="text" placeholder="Вставте нужную ссылку или хеш сюда">
        <button type="button" class="position_center borders">Тык!</button>
    </body>
{% endblock %}
```

Пробовал временно обойтись без кнопки, прописав инпуту следующую конструкцию:

```
method="GET" name="q" value="{{ request.args.get('q', '') }}"
```

и старался забрать переменную `q`:

```
def some_sum():
    q = request.args.get['q']
    print(q)
```

Но, мягко говоря, все тщетно.

Абсолютно не понимаю как по кнопке выполнить определенную функцию.

UPD:

Разобрался. Если вдруг у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, то вот код и скрины.

Первый файл:

```
index.html

{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block body %}
    <body>
        <form action="/a" method="post">
            <input class="position_center borders" type="text" placeholder="Вставте нужную ссылку или хеш сюда"
                   name="q">
            <button type="submit" class="position_center borders">Тык!</button>
        </form>
    </body>
{% endblock %}
```

Второй файл:

```
blueprint.py

from flask import Blueprint
from flask import render_template, request

urlToHash = Blueprint('urlToHash', __name__, template_folder='templates')


@urlToHash.route('/a', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def urlToHash_func():
    q = request.form['q']
    return render_template('urlToHash/test.html', q=q)
```

Третий файл:

```
test.html

{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block body %}
    <body>
    <h1>{{ q }}</h1>>
    </body>
{% endblock %}
```

Скрины:
[image: Поле ввода]

[image: Вывод]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужна форма а не просто поле и кнопка.

```
<body>
    <form action="/url" method="post">
       <input class="position_center borders" type="text" placeholder="Вставте нужную ссылку или хеш сюда">
       <button type="submit" class="position_center borders">Тык!</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

При этом вам надо тип кнопки сделать `submit` а вместо `/url` указать ваш урл роутинга которая перехватывается вашей функцией `some_sum`.

Ну и вашей функции `some_sum` указать декоратор вашего урла.
Для моего примера должно быть так:

```
@app.route('/url')
def some_sum():
    q = request.args.get['q']
    return q
```

И не печатать `q` а возвращать как ответ.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Немного не то, что было нужно, но тут я уже сам скорее виноват, плохо объяснил. В любом случае с вашей подачи сам во всем разобрался. Плюс в карму.